# Updating view (ProcessFlow) data in an oData callback function?

Tags: data-binding, callback, odata, sapui5

I am trying to populate a Process Flow (https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.ProcessFlow/preview) with data from an oData v2 service. For this, I have implemented a callback function (attachRequestCompleted) which reads the data for the lanes and nodes from the resp. entities in my oData service and transforms it into JSON.

At the end of the callback function, this code passes the data on to the Process Flow:

```
            var oPF1JSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            oPF1JSONModel.setProperty("/lanes", lanes);
            oPF1JSONModel.setProperty("/nodes", nodes);
            viewPf1.setModel(oPF1JSONModel, "pf1");
            viewPf1.byId("processflow1").updateModel();
```

However, regardless of whether I use the data from my oData service or hard-code the sample data, this message appears:
[processflowerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olV8B.png)

I'm using Web IDE and the latest Chrome. The UI5 Inspector can't find anything either.

Any C&C is welcome, as I'm really out of ideas.

Thanks & regards,

Max

Comment: I guess the first thing I'd wonder about is whether you indeed defined position 0 multiple times?

Comment: Neither in the sample data (https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.ProcessFlow/code), nor coming from my oData service. In the debugger, my JSON object looks exactly like the one in the sample. This error does not make any sense to me :(.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the code being inside a callback function? In the SAP sample all of this is done in the Init method of the controller.

Comment: I think I'd just take the exlored code and start reworking it step by step towards your code and see when it breaks. That may give you a good pointer.